# How to fix Meta.fields cannot be a string. Did you mean to type: ('name')

Tags: python, django

Currently I have a script that allows a user to add new Hotel using a Form Here is the script.

I get the following Error Exception
AddHotelForm.Meta.fields cannot be a string. Did you mean to type: ('name',)?

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    8000/hotel/new
Django Version:     1.6.2
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:

AddHotelForm.Meta.fields cannot be a string. Did you mean to type: ('name',)?

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py in **new**, line 261

I Seem not to get it I'have checked it several times and don't seem to find a solution to it.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from forms import AddHotelForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from hotel.models import hotel

def create(request):

    if request.POST:

         form = AddHotelForm(request.POST)

         if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/articles/all/')

    else:

         form = AddHotelForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('add_hotel.html', args)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from user.models import user


class hotel(models.Model):

    publisher = models.ForeignKey(user)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from models import hotel


class AddHotelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        models = hotel
        fields = ('name')
```

add_hotel.html

```
{% block content%}
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        li {
            padding:5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            list-style: none;

        }

        .errorlist {
            background-color: red;
            color:white;
            padding: 1px;
            width:150px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: arial, serif;

        }

        label {
            display: block;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: arial, serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/hotel/new/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <uL style="display:block;">
            {{form.as_ul}}
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Hotel">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
 {% endblock%}
```

Comment: The error not only states precisely what the problem is, but also tells you *exactly* how to fix it. Did you try following that advice?

Answer (score 24):

So the problem seems to be exactly what is stated in the error message.

Your problem is that this:

```
("name")
```

is not the same as this:

```
("name",)
```

Try it:

```
>>> type(("name"))
<type 'str'>
>>> type(("name",))
<type 'tuple'>
```

So to fix it change your form definition:

```
class AddHotelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        models = hotel # This should be "model" not "models".
        fields = ('name',)
```

Comment: I updated the error and added the comma to the forms.py but now i get "ModelForm has no model class specified"

and points to form = AddHotelForm()

Comment: Look at my edit. You need to change "models" to "model".

Comment: for crying out loud mate... this was exactly the problem, though, to be honest, I first thought you're bonkers. Why or why?! this makes no friggin' sense! everywhere else  in Django world a trailing comma can be ignored... for crying out loud =(( though extra credits to you for giving a tuple vs string explanation there